# Eclipse ROM on Droid X2 = no Wifi

Tags: wi-fi, custom-roms, motorola-droid-x2

Having a problem with a Droid X2 after installing the Eclipse ROM.  The Wifi connection won't connect, and upon looking in the settings window it just says, "Error".

Phone-> About shows version 2.3.5

Comment: You went through the whole "install 2.3.4 SBF, temp unroot, update to 2.3.5, etc." process, yes?  If so, did you use the 2.3.5-418 update?

Comment: I was on 2.3.5-418 when I flashed to Eclipse - do I need to 2.3.4-380, then use the "Official OTA" update to 2.3.5-418?